# Array element not defined after I print it with console.log?? Seems to be only defined after I remove that line..? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, return, console.log

I want to return number of truthy values in the array below.

```
const array = [1,2,3,'',2];

function countTruthy (array) {


let numberCount = 0;

for (let item of array) 

    console.log(item)

    if (item) numberCount++;

    return numberCount;
```

But this only works after I remove this line.

```
console.log(item)
```

Otherwise I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
at countTruthy?

Why?

Bonus question - No matter how my return statement is indented I get the same result back... but should it be under the "if statement" or the "for loop"? Why?

Comment: start by console logging array and numberCount and see what the value of those are. You can't troubleshoot if you can't see all of your data. Never assume anything is working, always test your assumptions. We can't troubleshoot item until we know what the surrounding data looks like

Comment: you need to check your braces

Comment: You need curly braces for your "for" statement; that's after the `(let item of array)`. You're also missing a semicolon for your console.log (that is if it matters in your environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will be useful for you:

When you don't use braces '{}' in the "for", any loop or condition, only the next line is taken for that process. In your case, if you remove the log, the item is recognized by the "for", but if you add the log in the next line, as it does not have the keys "{}" the "for" only operates with the next line and the item no longer belongs to the "for" so it is no longer recognized and you would have to declare it outside the "for"

```js
const array = [1,2,3,'',2];

function countTruthy (array) {

  let numberCount = 0;

    for (let item of array) 
    {
      console.log(item);
      if (item) numberCount++;
    }
    return numberCount;
}

countTruthy(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are missing some scoping (ie. "{ }"). With your current implementation, the for statement will only execute the `console.log` that's why if you remove it then it executes the `if(item)...` and all works

try

```
for (let item of array) {
  console.log(item);
  if (item) {
    numberCount++;
  }
}
return numberCount;
```

One important thing to note is that Javascript is not a "positional" language, so no matter how you indent the code it will execute the same, what matters is the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an indentation issue. Use brackets to close the function and for loop like this:

```
const array = [1,2,3,'',2];

function countTruthy (array) {

  let numberCount = 0;

  for (let item of array) {
    console.log(item)

    if (item) numberCount++;

  }
  return numberCount;
}
```